# Don't return duplicate title in WordPress loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, unique

I have this standard loop for returning titles of a custom post type:

```
    <ul>
    <?php 
        $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'food_types',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1
        );
        $query = new WP_Query($args);
        while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><?php echo the_title();?></li>
        <?php endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
    </ul>
```

The problem is that there are often posts with the same title.

I need my loop modified so that there is only one instance of any given post title returned in the loop.

For example, if there are posts with these titles...

```
Tomato
Orange
Orange
Apple
Apple
Egg
Banana
Banana
```

...then the loop should only return this:

```
Tomato
Orange
Apple
Egg
Banana
```

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you are only worried about fruit names, it may make sense to create a separate data set for it and not even bother looping all posts and removes the burden of tracking names inside the loop.

Edit: It makes sense to move this functionality into a function so you can easily reuse it anywhere.

```
// functions.php
function getFruits() {
    $query = new WP_Query([
        'post_type'       => 'food_types',
        'posts_per_page'  => -1
    ]);

    // When to use wp_reset_postdata(): https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/144344/145214
    wp_reset_postdata();

    // Extracts out just post_titles and makes new array
    $fruits = array_column( $query->posts, 'post_title'); // PHP7+

    // Gets unique values
    $fruits = array_unique( $fruits );

    return $fruits;
}

// template
$fruits = getFruits();

// Then all you have to do is loop that list
foreach($fruits as $fruit) : ?>

    <li>
        <?= $fruit ?>
    </li>

<?php endforeach;
```

Comment: Nice solution. I will just add from myself that if you use get_posts you have to only put $query in array_column function.

Answer (score 0):

Is duplication in the database ok, if not, then you might want to run a script to remove duplicates, as it can result in a performance hit.

If there are not too many items in the list, then a quick solution for your current code could simply to add each title to an array, and then continue the while loop if the item was previously added.

Use: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

So something like this.. NB: this is just in concept... I did not test the code.:

```
<ul>
<?php 
    $args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'food_types',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    $list = array();
    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 
    if(in_array(get_the_title(), $list)){ continue; }
    $list[] = get_the_title();
    ?>
    <li><?php echo get_the_title();?></li>
    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</ul>
```

*Modified to use get_the_title() as you explained in comments

Comment: That actually nearly works. I just had to change to get_the_title() instead. That aside, a problem has occurred I didn't expect. If I limit the posts to 10 for example, sometimes it might only return one result because of the most recent 10 posts have the same title. I'll mark your post as the correct answer anyway (I've made an edit) because it works. But if you have any suggestions for this new problem, I'm all ears.

Comment: It depends on the situation. Is it just the title you're querying? If you're into SQL, then instead of using WP_Query, you can create your own query with wpdb and `SELECT DISTINCT post_title FROM $wpdb->posts` for example... https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb WordPress also has a command called posts_distinct But it seems limited to certain situations, maybe if you wanted to check still https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_distinct

Answer (score 0):

`the_title()` does not require to echo. check:

```
<ul>
    <?php 
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'food_types',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><?php the_title();?></li>
    <?php endwhile;
     wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: You didn't answer the question.  Your response would fit better as a comment.

Comment: "the_title() does not require to echo. check:" -> Correct, my bad. I didn't notice that.